# Search in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question, I am making a query with Firebase, I will leave my code below, but the problem is that I want that when I find the value I ask, I stop the search and also do some process (in this case a simple sum to a value that is located in Firebase)

I check it in the Firebase console and it enters like an infinite loop and the number changes at all times.

Some idea to be able to solve this. Thank you

```
Query busqueda = databaseReference.child("empresas").orderByChild("monto_compraventa").equalTo(gasto_compra);

busqueda.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            boolean proceso = false;
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
             if(dataSnapshot1.exists() && !proceso){
                 Intent pago = new Intent(Comprar.this, PagoRealizado.class);
                 startActivity(pago);
                 finish();



                Map<String, Object> actualizarmonto = new HashMap<>();
                actualizarmonto.put("monto", monto_actual-monto_gasto_hoy);
                databaseReference1.updateChildren(actualizarmonto);



             }else{
                 proceso = true;

             }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain from the code you shared, since we can't know what `busqueda` and `databaseReference1` are.

But most likely you're modifying the data that you've attach the listener. The modification then triggers the listener again, which modifies the data again. This repeats and repeats.

If you only want to read the data once and update it, you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`:

```
busqueda.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Comment: I did that, but I need to say so, to search at all times and when you find the value I ask for entry in your EditText, stop everything, go to an activity and update a number.

Do you think it's the only way to do it with the SingleValueEvent?

Comment: It's hard to say from your current code. To get the best help, see if you can isolate the problem into a single snippet of code with no external dependencies. For hints on how to do that and why it helps, see [creating a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).